# Omitting argument in command definition

Tags: macros, expansion, syntax, arguments

Sometimes I define model commands (`\foo` in the example below) and then particular commands based on that model (`\fool` in the example below). However, I am not entirely sure I am using the correct syntax.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mm}{#2#1}
\NewDocumentCommand\fool{}{\foo!}
\NewDocumentCommand\foot{m}{\foo!{#1}}

\begin{document}
   \fool{⟨sth⟩}, \foot{⟨sth⟩}
\end{document}
```

Do `\fool` and `\foot` behave differently? Is one better than the other? As I understand it, both `\fool{⟨sth⟩}` and `\foot{⟨sth⟩}` expand to `\foo!{⟨sth⟩}` and then to `⟨sth⟩!`, which is the expected result. Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Basically, you're applying the `moving arguments` technique. This is often used in the TeX/LaTeX core and package code, but is it really needed with `\NewDocumentCommand`? Using `\meaning\foot` and `\meaning\fool` shows that the code behind them is not the same

Answer (score 9):

TeX is a macro expansion language. If we look at some random definitions in `plain.tex`, we find some that only *appear* to have an argument. For instance

```
\def\line{\hbox to\hsize}
```

that should be called `\line{text}`. So, what appears to be the argument to `\line` is actually the argument to `\hbox to\hsize`.

The LaTeX model is more complicated. For instance, `\makebox` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\makebox{%
  \leavevmode
  \@ifnextchar(%)
    \@makepicbox
    {\@ifnextchar[\@makebox\mbox}}%
```

which has *no* argument. Grabbing the argument is deferred to `\@makepicbox`, `\@makebox` or `\mbox`, depending on the token that follows.

The same approach is used by `xparse`. If you look at the definition of `\foo` after your definition, you'll see

```
> \foo=\protected macro:
->\__xparse_start_expandable:nNNNNn {mm}\foo  \foo  \foo code ?{\__xparse_expandable_grab_m:w \__xparse_expandable_grab_m:w }.
```

so `\foo` has no argument (like `\makebox`). The arguments are actually grabbed by `\foo•code` (the bullet means a space in the name) in a quite complex way, because the aim is to be able to specify complex sequences of mandatory or optional arguments. Here is its definition:

```
> \foo code=\protected\long macro:
#1#2->#2#1.
```

On the other hand, if you did

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{O{x}m}
```

then the definition of `\foo` would be

```
> \foo=\protected macro:
->\__xparse_start:nNNnnn {O{x}m}\foo  \foo code {\__xparse_grab_D:w []\__xparse_grab_m_1:w }{{\prg_do_nothing: x}\c__xparse_no_value_tl }{}.
```

but `\foo•code` would be the same as before.

Similarly for `\fool` and `\foot`. Both version would work the same, eventually, because both will end up in

```
\foo•code ! {(sth)}
```

in the main input stream.

The only difference is that the second argument would be read twice with `\foot` and only once with `\fool`. A saving in time that's not worth the pain, in general.

A recommendation when using `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends is to always specify the full set of arguments. There are however cases where using the “reduced” version is easier, but they should be kept to a minimum for maximum readability of the code.